# Finding an Ember-Data row created with 'createRecord' and with null id value?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-power-select

I am using the following pattern in an Ember 3.8 project ...

**Situation**

When the user navigates to the route `foo/add` the `model` function in the Route definition uses `createRecord` to generate an empty `foo` record in the Data Store.

The foo/add template uses a `Component` which implements a form to enter `foo` details into. The form, in turn, uses an instance of ember-power-select for which [an onchange handler](https://ember-power-select.com/docs/action-handling) is defined in the `foo` form `Component`.

Once the form is displayed the user is free to use the power select.

When the `onchange` handler of the power select fires I want to update the record created initially by `createRecord`.

**Issue**

I can send an action to the foo/add `Controller` but how does the `Controller` find the row in the Data Store ? Because the row has not yet been inserted on the server it doesn't have the ID which will eventually be associated with it, the id value is in fact null.

**Alternatives**

I have read some references in old Ember material to being able to generate your own ID at the point of `createRecord` but I can't find a contemporary reference.

I'm open to a totally different approach so any suggestions welcome.

Finally, although I'm using the Data Store to hold data on the client side I'm not actually using Ember-Data to communicate with the server (not sure that makes any difference but I thought I would make it clear).

Answer (score 0):

you may use the Click [here](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-route-action-helper)
This may solve your issue.

Comment: Hi Bhabani - Thanks for your response. In fact my question was based on a misunderstanding of the situation but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could return the newly created record in the model hook of the route (it sounds like you are already doing this) and then access it in the controller by `this.get('model')`. If you plan on persisting it and having your server generate the record id you could do something like `api.post(record).then(response => store.pushRecord(response))` so then you would be able to find it by it's new server generated id. `store.peekRecord(response.id)`